# How can I ask Lucene to do simple, flat scoring?

Tags: lucene

Let me preface by saying that I'm not using Lucene in a very common way and explain how my question makes sense. I'm using Lucene to do searches in structured records. That is, each document, that is indexed, is a set of fields with short values from a given set. Each field is analysed and stored, the analysis producing usually no more than 3 and in most cases just 1 normalised token. As an example, imagine files for each of which we store two fields: the path to the file and a user rating in 1-5. The path is tokenized with a PathHierarchyTokenizer and the rating is just stored as-is. So, if we have a document like

```
path: "/a/b/file.txt"
rating: 3
```

This document will have for its path field the tokens "/a", "/a/b" and "/a/b/file.ext", and for rating the token "3".

I wish to score this document against a query like "path:/a path:/a/b path:/a/b/different.txt rating:1" and get a value of 2 - the number of terms that match.

My understanding and observation is that the score of the document depends on various term metrics and with many documents with many fields each, I most definitely am not getting simple integer scores.

Is there some way to make Lucene score documents in the outlined fashion? The queries that are run against the index are not generated by the users, but are built by the system and have an optional filter attached, meaning they all have a fixed form of several TermQuerys joined in a BooleanQuery with nothing like any fuzzy textual searches. Currently I don't have the option of replacing Lucene with something else, but suggestions are welcome for a future development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's something ready to use, so most probably you will need to implement your own scorer and use it when searching. For complicated cases you may want to [play around with queries](http://dev.fernandobrito.com/2012/10/building-your-own-lucene-scorer/), but for simple case like yours it should be enough to [overwrite `DefaultSimilarity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380188/custom-lucene-scoring-dot-product-between-field-boost-and-query-boost) setting `tf` factor to raw frequency (number of specified terms in document in question) and all other components to 1. Something like this:

```
public class MySimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float computeNorm(String field, FieldInvertState state) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public float tf(float freq) {
        return freq;
    }

    @Override
    public float idf(int docFreq, int numDocs) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

(Note, that `tf()` is the only method that returns something different than 1)

And the just [set similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#setSimilarity(org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity)) on `IndexSearcher`.