# Are there any rules for boosting factor range in solr/lucene queries?

Tags: solr, lucene

I know that solr uses normalization of floats to save memory and speed up computing by mapping them to 2 bytes representation.
So my question -- is it ok to use any float numbers to boost my terms in query (i.e., `a^0.00001 +b^0.11111`) or should I normolize them somehow to not lose precision of solr/lucene computation? Say make them between 1 to 1000 and make them power of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although index-time boosts are compressed and may lead to an important precision loss when computing scores (for example, see [In Lucene, why do my boosted and unboosted documents get the same score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899031/in-lucene-why-do-my-boosted-and-unboosted-documents-get-the-same-score/8068457#8068457)), this is not the case for query-time boosts.

Query-time boosts are Java `float`s and participate in scores using Java arithmetical operators. Of course there can be [accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) with floating-point arithmetics, but this is very unlikely to influence the scoring in a way that documents appear in an irrelevant order in a result set.